# Image Swap on Hover with Text Link on Top

Tags: internet-explorer, css, hover, css-transitions

I am a novice at html/css so please bear that in mind for those who are generous enough to offer help.

I am trying to do a image swap on hover and a text link on top of the image which changes color on hover to accomodate the hovered image. My goal is to get the entire area of the graphic clickable and a link.

I somehow managed to get it to work on Chrome, but fails miserably in Internet Explorer. 
I don't expect to get the transition effects to work for internet explorer.

This is the code I have. I know it's probably very messy. 
http://studyusa.com/images/-IEHover-Issue.html

I tried solution from different angles adding padding to , giving it a  with height and width, transparent background .gif, and a few JS snippets that I have no idea whether it's doing anything or not...

The JS code I took from:

http:// css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

and here

http: //alistapart.com/article/dropdowns

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">



        /* 3 Features Starts Here */

         div#threefeatures-container { 
            margin: 0 auto; 
            width: 600px;
            height: 120px;
            padding: 0px;   
            border: none;
        } 

        div.threefeatures {
            position: relative;
            width: 190px;
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
        }

        div.threefeatures-margin {
            margin: 0 15px;
        }       

        div.threefeatures a.threefeatures-text-link {
            position: absolute; 
            padding-top: 12px;
            color: black; 
            width: 100%;
            height: 108px;
            font: bold 14px "Helvetica";  
            z-index: 100;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            display: block;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            background: url(
            http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Transparent.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;

        }       

        div.threefeatures a:link span {
            display: block;
            height: 110px;
                }

        div.threefeatures a:hover {
            color: white;
            -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        }

        div.threefeatures img { 
            -webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out; 
            -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out; 
            -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out; 
            transition: all 550ms ease-in-out; 
        }

        div.threefeatures img.img1 { 
            /* IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
            /* IE 5-7 */
              filter: alpha(opacity=1); 
            /* Netscape */
              -moz-opacity: 1;  
            /* Safari 1.x */
              -khtml-opacity: 1;
            /* Good browsers */
              opacity: 1;     
            zoom: 1;      
            position: absolute;  /*collapses images together*/
            top:0;
            right:0;
            width:190px;
        } 


        div.threefeatures:hover img.img1 { 

            /* IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
            /* IE 5-7 */
              filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            /* Netscape */
              -moz-opacity: 0;      
            /* Safari 1.x */
              -khtml-opacity: 0;            
            /* Good browsers */
              opacity: 0;             
              zoom: 1;
        }   

        div.threefeatures a img.img2 {
            /* IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
            /* IE 5-7 */
              filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            /* Netscape */
              -moz-opacity: 0;
            /* Safari 1.x */
              -khtml-opacity: 0;    
            /* Good browsers */
              opacity: 0;     
              zoom: 1;
              position: absolute;
              top:0;
              right:0;
              width:190px;
        }


        div.threefeatures:hover a img.img2  {
            /* IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
            /* IE 5-7 */
              filter: alpha(opacity=1);     
            /* Netscape */
              -moz-opacity: 1;      
            /* Safari 1.x */
              -khtml-opacity: 1;    
            /* Good browsers */
              opacity: 1;     
              zoom: 1;
        } 


   </style>
   </head>


      <body>
                <!--Hover Script for IE-->
        <script>    
        startList = function() {
        if (document.all&&document.getElementById) {
        navRoot = document.getElementById("threefeatures-container");
        for (i=0; i<navRoot.childNodes.length; i++) {
        node = navRoot.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeName=="DIV") {
        node.onmouseover=function() {
        this.className+=" over";
          }
          node.onmouseout=function() {
          this.className=this.className.replace
                (" over", "");
           }
           }
          }
         }
        }
        window.onload=startList;
        </script>

<!--3 Features Hover Click-->
    <script>
        $(".threefeatures").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        return false;
        });
    </script>

    <!--3 Features Starts Here-->

    <div id="threefeatures-container">
        <div class="threefeatures">

            <a class="threefeatures-text-link" href="http://studyusa.com/en/schools/"><span>Search Schools</span></a>

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-01.png" class="img1" alt="Use Study in the USA's advanced U.S. Schools Search for International Students to find the perfect school for you">

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-02.png" class="img2" alt="Use Study in the USA's advanced U.S. Schools Search for International Students to find the perfect school for you">

        </div>

        <div class="threefeatures threefeatures-margin">

            <a class="threefeatures-text-link" a href="http://studyusa.com/en/advisors/"><span>Ask Questions</span></a>

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Ask-Questions-01.png" class="img1" alt="Get your questions about Studying in the USA answered by asking our adivisors for free">

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Ask-Questions-02.png" class="img2" alt="Get your questions about Studying in the USA answered by asking our adivisors for free"></a>

        </div>

        <div class="threefeatures">

            <a class="threefeatures-text-link" href="http://studyusa.com/en/resources/"><span>Read Articles</span></a>

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Read-Articles-01.png" class="img1" alt="Read Articles and learn how to Study in the USA">

            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Read-Articles-02.png" class="img2" alt="Read Articles and learn how to Study in the USA">

        </div>
    </div>  


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your code was messy indeed so I rebuilt your page and came up with this. I hope you will pick up a few things after investigating the new code. Feel free to ask if you're not sure about something. The code below should work at least for IE8+.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

#three-featured a img { border: none; } /* IE fix */

#three-featured li {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     width: 190px;
     height: 120px;
     margin: 0 5px;
     *display: inline; /* IE fix */
    zoom: 1; /* IE fix */
}

#three-featured li a {
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#three-featured li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

#three-featured li span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica"; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#three-featured li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#schools a {
    background: transparent url('http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-01.png') no-repeat center center;
}

#questions a {
    background: transparent url('http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Ask-Questions-01.png') no-repeat center center;
}

#articles a {
    background: transparent url('http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Read-Articles-01.png') no-repeat center center;
}
</style>

<ul id="three-featured">
    <li id="schools">
        <a href="http://studyusa.com/en/schools/">
            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-02.png" alt="Your alt">
            <span>Search Schools</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="questions">
       <a href="http://studyusa.com/en/advisors/" data-bg="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-02.png"> 
           <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Ask-Questions-02.png" alt="your at" />
           <span>Ask Questions</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li id="articles">
        <a href="http://studyusa.com/en/resources/" data-bg="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Find-Schools-02.png">
            <img src="http://studyusa.com/common/homepage_test/images/3-Features-Read-Articles-02.png" alt="Your alt" />
            <span>Read Articles</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       jQuery("img", this).stop().fadeIn();
    },  
    mouseleave: function() {
       jQuery("img", this).stop().fadeOut();     
    }
},'#three-featured a'); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BDtGG/ (use this site as often as you can, when you ask a question - create jsfiddle too and paste link to it here on stackoverflow)

Comment: Wow, really appreciate you looking into this. 
I'm still looking at your code trying to figure out what you did. 

But in the meantime, there are areas where the hovering over the button only changes the text color to white and some areas where it doesn't turn clickable. I recorded a video. Link below. I'm using Chrome. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kecjbg0cgnes4wh/image-swap-hover.m4v

Comment: It also appears the space for the LI position is not aligned with the IMAGE position. How would I get these to lineup?

Screenshot Link Below. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwti4liuy8uvmsi/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-05%20at%203.33.33%20PM.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HtamL/

I edited the code you gave me to line up the LI and IMAGE. 
Also, is there a reason why you use display: inline-block? Inline block ads some white space and I'd like tighter control over the spacing between so I changed it to float:left. I tried to add margin left and right to the middle LI but it didn't seem to work so I took it out of the jsfiddle.